# Java find last member in index of array

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

So let say I have an array of size 10 with index range from 0 to 9.
I add a bunch of elements in and stop adding at index 6. So with array.length, I can know that the size of the array is 10, but how do I find which index contain the last value and after that is empty? Am I suppose to do a loop and stop at index == null?

I mimic an arraylist by create a dynamic array that grow when the size is full.

Arg, forgot to tell you guys, if the array is int, then the empty slots will be 0?

Comment: You should use an `ArrayList` instead

Comment: Do you want to iterate the array?? Or I understand something wrong? Ok, I got it wrong.. But you should definitely use an `ArrayList`

Comment: You keep track of it, that's how. Don't go relying on null's - what if you put a null in it? It'd disappear.

Comment: that is my assignment... use normal array and make a dynamic that have a method that make a bigger array when the capacity is filled up.... I not allowed to use array list guys...

Comment: @RyokoNela You cannot have tradional array behave like a dynamic one.. It has a fixed size.. That cannot be changed..

Comment: @RohitJain sure you can, how do you think ArrayList is implemented? The length can't be changed no, but you could just create a new one and copy the elements over.

Comment: @RohitJain: I dont do that... what I saying is I have a method like this: 'code' private void ensureCapacity(int size_wanted)
    {
      int max_capacity = storage.length;
      if (size_wanted > max_capacity) 
      {
        max_capacity = max_capacity * GROW_FACTOR +1; 
        storage = Arrays.copyOf(storage, max_capacity); // increases array size + copy contents
      } 
    }'code' That make sure the stuffs is copied to a bigger one when current array is full... and I making a removeAt (index) method, hence the question up there.

Comment: @RyokoNela. OK.. So, what problem are you facing?? You tried that code right?

Comment: @harold. Yeah I thought OP wants to use just one array..

Comment: I need to make a removeAt(index) method. I could remove in between, no problem, I can just remove the thing, and shift everything on the right to the left. But let say I want to remove the last member in the array. How do I know I am at the end so I dont need to shift anything else since it is empty after the position that I want to remove?

Comment: @RyokoNela. Are you not allowed to use any in-built methods?

Comment: I actually can, I import ArrayList, so I guess i can use it. Well, if you have a suggestion, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `java.util.ArrayList`. There you no need to think about index and it is resizable-array implementation.

At the time of array creation by default all values are null so if you do not insert any value  at any index (may be at end or beginning or middle of array) it would be just null. So you should put null check to verify.

Comment: As I said I making something implement the same principle that apply for arraylist... that why I need all this stuffs.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is you assignment a trick is to add a variable to follow the number of elements added.

So you can have a `public int size = 0` variable and change you add and remove operations to increase and decrease this variable whenever you add or remove an element.

Then in you add method you can have a simple check to see if you need to expand the array

```
if (size == array.length)
   expandArray
```

Comment: Can I declare the checking variable as local for the add method? I am not allow to add more class fields. Wait, actually the specs dont forbid me from adding more... look like I can add a class field.

Comment: if you made it local it will be set to zero (because is essence you will have a new instance of this variable) everytime you call the add method so it will not work, If you can't add class fields then I don't see other option that to iterate the array to check if it filled before you add a new element. Strange though that you are not allowed to add class variables.

Comment: If you cannot add the variable then a trick is to check if the array is filled is to check that the last item is not null (or zero) so a check if (array[size] != null) could help assuming that: you add elements in order (from 0 to size without skipping elements) and null (or 0 in case of int array) is not a valid number